# Why is $GL_n (\mathbb{R})$ uncountable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've been given an example of a group:

> For every integer $n\geq1$, the set of $n\times n$ invertible matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ is a group under matrix multiplication, denoted by $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, is uncountable.

How do I prove that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is uncountable?

Here are my thoughts:

For $n=1$, $GL_n(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$ hence it is uncountable.

For $n>1$, do I consider $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ as a group with $n^2$ elements hence its cardinality is at most $|\mathbb{R}^{n^2}|$, and again $|\mathbb{R}|$ is uncountable, so $|\mathbb{R}^{n^2}|$ is also uncountable?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In theory you have only given upper bounds with continuum cardinality. You also need a lower bound. Like how many diagonal metrices are in there?

Comment: Well, we have an injective map from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, so if the latter was countable, so would the former.

Comment: $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, so you need to show that an uncountable set minus a point is still uncountable. For larger $n$, you just need to show that you can find an uncountable set inside, so consider scalar diagonal matrices for example.

Comment: @Joppy that's easier than what I had in mind! I was thinking about rotation matrices.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the fact that $\det: GL_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ is surjective.

Comment: It's really the simplest way! (+1)

Comment: Or that $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to GL_n(\mathbb R), \lambda \mapsto \lambda I_n$is injective

Comment: Or identity plus $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ in the top-right co-ordinate.